# Using AJAX to run a php file on load

Tags: php, ajax, google-chrome

How can I use AJAX to run a PHP file when the page is loaded, I'm trying to create a small chrome extension and need to run my PHP file however nothing seems to be working I have this so far

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(
    "GET",
    "my_php_file.php",
    true);
req.send(null);
```

Comment: check out jQuery, it makes doing ajax 1000x easier.

Comment: check out Mootools, it makes maintaining javascript codes 1000x readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with jquery...

(put at the bottom of your page)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container-id-to-load-into').load('file-to-load.php);
 });
</script>
```

I tried a couple solutions on my own that didn't work b/c I needed to do multiple calls on page load and finally went with the JQuery solution I could find.

Hope that helps...